# "Add to Cart" button in HTML table doubles row height but sits in the top half of cell?

Tags: html, css, button, paypal

I am writing a new website with a single long catalog.
Each item is on a separate row of an HTML table with an "Add to Cart" Paypal button in the right-hand cell.

I'm new to PayPal and choose to use small buttons to affect the rows the least amount possible.  But, when I added the button, the row doubled in height and the button is sitting in the top-half of the cell.  At the moment, you can see it at http://www.247caregivingproducts.com/catalog.htm.

How do I add a button without changing the height of the row more than the size of the button?

Comment: The current look of the row is good . You should just add this : `style="position:relative;top:50%"` to center your paypal button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form itself is adding height so if you change the height of the form to the height of the button it will be fine.

```
td form {
 height: 21px !important;
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully, Flo. Thanks!

Now that I know that it was the form that added the height and how to change the CSS to compensate - I have to do the rest of the buttons. Any suggestion on keeping my hands from hurting after doing 100+ buttons?

Comment: Don't forget to up vote the post for others who have the same problem! :)

Comment: Flo, I would happily, if I could.  But, I pressed the up arrow and received a pop-up message saying an up-vote requires a 15 reputation?

Comment: You can do the css in the head of the document or in a external style sheet. If you opt to do it in the <head> all you have to do is this and you only have to do it the once.

`<style>
td form {
 height: 21px !important;
}
</style>`

Comment: Yes, I copied what you sent and pasted, uploaded to my webhost, checked it with my browser and saw that it worked.  I put it in the head of the document so it would apply only to this catalog, in case I wanted to use td form with a different style in some other part of the website.

Comment: If you want to use a form in a td on this page you can just give the td a `class="button"` and change your selector to `td.button form {};`
Don't forget to come tick the answer once you can.

Comment: @Steven You should accept Flo's answer by click on right(tick) symbol. if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because image will take the extra space. You can display it none like:

```
#catalog img {
    display: none;
}
```

And make button vertical you can use following css:

```
input {
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
```

If you don't want `display:none` image then refer Flo's answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You shouldn't use this method because paypal actually uses the img load for a count. Otherwise this would be better.

Comment: Yes that's why i wrote. *"If you don't want display:none image then refer Flo's answer."*.

Comment: Just explaining for the OP. He doesn't know this.